# SQL - How to transpose a dataframe

Tags: sql, transpose

I have a table as follows

**co_id founded_yr  co_typ_nam**

20357677.0  NaN Public Company

319092.0    1887.0  Public Company

685347.0    1925.0  Public Company

345779.0    NaN Public Company

596117.0    1668.0  Public Company

I'd like to transpose this table such that each of my co_id i.e. company ID are columns and the other columns are rows. My expected outcome is something on the following lines

```
           co_id 1   co_id 2   co_id 3
```

founded_yr      1947      1945      2002

company_type    Public    Pvt

Please note that this is a sample dataframe and my actual table has 100+ column which is why I want to transpose the table as it will make reading the table a lot easier.

Comment: Please read here how to create a table: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post Also add a table which shows your expected outcome.

Comment: Added expected table format